# javascript code work after I do inspect second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to get data from element on iframe using jquery but my code can work only if I inspect my page second time then will work correctly

at the first time I get this message

```js
$("#contact_form label.control-label ").eq(1).html("Prenom");
VM737:1 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

at the second time i do inspect the code work

```js
$("#contact_form label.control-label ").eq(1).html("Prenom");
[label.col-sm-4.control-label.ng-binding.fb-required, prevObject: init(7), context: document]
```

my page code of the page I want to use the iframe

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<iframe id="ly-id-iframe" src="https://URL-OF-MY-THEPAGE"  frameborder=0 scrolling="no" width="650px" height="600px"></iframe>

<script>

    $("#contact_form label.control-label ").eq(0).html("Nom");
    $("#contact_form label.control-label ").eq(1).html("Prenom");
    $("#contact_form label.control-label ").eq(2).html("PCourriel");

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

the code is working only if I inspect the page with chrome second time
i inspect the page and in console i write 
$("#contact_form label.control-label ").eq(0).html("Nom");
it's not working but if I inspect the page without reload it the second time the code change.

Comment: " i do inspect" - what does this mean?

Comment: Move the jQuery script include as high in the html head tag as possible. Also put in your script code at the very end of the body tag.

Comment: i did but still getting this problem

Answer (score 1):

This error : `$ is not a function` usually happen when you run jQuery syntax before your jQuery is loaded! So you need to check it first, make sure your jQuery is load before run any scripts which use jQuery syntax.